# Display Image of ComboBox Item Selection

Tags: vb.net, combobox, picturebox

I want to display an image when the user selects an item from the ComboBox. Which Property should I use?

Answer (score 0):

`Combobox.SelectedValue` to obtain the selected item, and `PictureBox.Image` to set the image you wanto to display.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I one of the items is "Ladder" as an example, What is the code should I write?

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is to store an image in the `Tag` property of each item in the combobox.

Another is to wrap the image in a class/struct with a string property to display the text you want through the ToString override.